# Draw shapes in PrimeFaces graphicImage

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to draw a shape (Simply a rectangle)  once the user select a region in a graphical image ? I found an utility in showcase that crops image but it doesn't draw the rectangular shape. is there a native component probably that I miss that can do this ? Or maybe some combination to get the expected result ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to draw the shape ON image?

Comment: Hello, Yes I want the shapes to be drawn on image. Thank you.